# Returning Rendered HTML from Chatbot

Tags: javascript, jquery, chatbot

I am using the chatbot from liouh (https://github.com/liouh/chat-bot). When I attempt to return a URL, it gives me unrendered/raw HTML instead of a link. How can I return a rendered link given the Google scenario below? Thank you

[image]

```js
function chatBot() {
    // current user input
    this.input;

    this.respondTo = function(input) {
        this.input = input.toLowerCase();

        if(this.match('link to google'))
            return "<a href='http://google.com'>Google.com</a>";

        if(this.input == 'noop')
            return;

        return "I dont know the answer to '" + input + "'. You can teach me that via the link at the top of this page.";
    }

    this.match = function(regex) {
        return new RegExp(regex).test(this.input);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like in line 54 of `index.js` you need to change the code from `line.find('.text').text(text);` to `line.find('.text').html(text);` - this will append the incoming reply as HTML instead of plain text. Want to try that?

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much, ochi!

Comment: Happy I could help;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in line 54 of `index.js` you need to change the code from

```
line.find('.text').text(text);
```

to

```
line.find('.text').html(text);
```

this will append the incoming reply as HTML instead of plain text.